# javascript delay and show gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Do you know how I can implement a javascript delay with animated gif when button is clicked? I have the button click functionality, but I want to add a 2 second delay, with gif. Here is my working javascript, without delay. Thank you.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/Video/Upload.aspx/');
        $('#myFrame').attr('width', '500');
        $('#myFrame').attr('height', '200');
        $('#vid').hide();
        $('#vid2').show();
        $('#myFrame').show();
    });
});
```

I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
$(function openVideo() {
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/Video/Upload.aspx/');
        $('#myFrame').attr('width', '500');
        $('#myFrame').attr('height', '200');
        $('#vid').hide();
        $('#vid2').show();
        $('#myFrame').show();
    });
});
setTimeout(openVideo, 2000);
```

Comment: Google [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [javascript setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
function functionName() {
    // do stuff.
}

setTimeout(functionName, 2000);
```

Or like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // do stuff.
}, 2000);
```

So in your example it might look like this:

```
$(function openVideo() {
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        var delay = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myFrame').attr('src', '/Video/Upload.aspx/');
            $('#myFrame').attr('width', '500');
            $('#myFrame').attr('height', '200');
            $('#vid').hide();
            $('#vid2').show();
            $('#myFrame').show();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ujijet/1/edit)

Comment: @mlg74 I edited my answer with relevant code for your situation, and a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Show the GIF using your preferred method (`appendChild`, `$.append()`, `innerHTML`...)

Then use `setTimeout(function() {/* do stuff here */}, 2000)` to implement a 2-second delay.

Two seconds is a long time, though. Any delay of more than 0.1 second is usually considered unacceptable without a very good reason.

Comment: you are right about the 2 seconds. I will probably do with less, but normal timing just seems like its too fast, so I want to slow it down just a hair. I tried the idea you said with setTimeout, and it didn't work. see above. let me know if you can see what I'm doing wrong..thanks again..

Comment: Never put function defitions inside `$(...)` unless you very specifically want that function to only be available to that particular ready script.